# Get Model instance from Form without saving

Tags: django, django-forms

Let say I have a django ModelForm which I want to edit before saving.

For example,

Instead of this

> ```
> model_instance = form.save()
> ```

I would like to do something like this

> ```
> model_instance = form.get_model()
> model_instance.edit() #say add a new field which is not available on form
> model_instance.save()
> ```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
```

will return you a object of the model without saving to the DB

you can then add value of some field which is not available on form

```
model_instance.some_field = value
model_instance.save()
```

Comment: I just found it somewhere and was on my way to add the answer myself. :)

Comment: If you use `form.save(commit=False)`, django will not save ManyToMany relations.  You must call `form.save_m2m()` after you save the instance yourself.  [Django ModelForms#Save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: Thanks. What confused me was that I wanted to refer to form.instance, but it's only available after save() is invoked.

Answer (score 9):

Also:

```
model_instance = form.instance
# edit
model_instance.save()
```

Comment: As of 2016 is this the best practice for this?

Comment: If you are trying to get the model instance from the __init__ or any method of a ModelForm instance, simply calling self.instance will get you the model bound to the ModelForm.